# stop for loop when get a specific value

Tags: java, android

i have a for loop which retrives from database names .. i want when i got a specific name to stop the loop and get out of it..

tried this but didn't work :

```
for (int i = 0; i < member .length(); i++) {

    JSONObject c = member .getJSONObject(i);

    // Storing each json item in variable
    String username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
    s1=inputName.getText().toString();
    if (username.equals(s1)){

        suc=1;
        return null;
    }
    else {

        suc=0;
    }
}
```

also i tried break; but didn't work either.

how to do it ?

**UPDATE**

This code is working fine, i found that the mistake is in another part of the code.

Comment: add a variable like bool abc = false; and chabge its value to make true; then after if else u can check if abc is true then break;

Comment: in a a if statement when the name is equal to the name you want i = member .lenght()

Comment: If this loop does not stop, then `username.equals(s1)` returns `false`. Try adding debug output in your else case.

Comment: Could you provide sample input output? Print the s1 value before if clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try a `do ... while` loop

```
int i = 0;

do {
  JSONObject c = member.getJSONObject(i);
  String username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);

  i++;
} while(!username.equals(inputName.getText().toString() && i<member.length());
```

This loop ends, when the username is equal to the inputName or when the end of the list is reached.

Comment: This code assumes that there is always at least one member. The condition has to be evaluated at the top. Try member.length() == 0, and you get and IndexOutOfBounds exception.

Comment: Your answer deviates from initial approach without any explanation.

Comment: sorry its working the mistake is in another part of the code.. thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is get out of the loop, then use `break` instead of `return null`.  The `break` statement terminates the innermost `switch`, `for`, `while`, or `do-while` statement.